# Entering text into an alert

Tags: selenium, capybara

I'm currently having difficulty writing a test that enters text into an alert prior to accepting/dismissing said alert.

I'm able to accept an alert with:

`page.driver.browser.switch_to.alert.accept`

However, when I attempt to use the following to enter text into the alert with:
`page.driver.browser.switch_to.alert.text("test")`

I get the following error:

`Failure/Error: page.driver.browser.switch_to.alert.text("test")
 ArgumentError:
 wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)`

Does anyone happen to have any experience with this workflow?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update that works:

```
    prompt = page.driver.browser.switch_to.alert
    prompt.send_keys('test')
    prompt.accept
```